# Pyqt5 return value in a qtablewidget

Tags: pyqt5

im trying to recover a value from a qtablewidget and i have two problems:

First: when i clicked pushbutton i get tablewidget.currentrow but when i change and press another row one, the row printed is not correct.

Second: How can i get the currentrow first column value?

Thanks in advance

```
def loadtable():
database = DataBase()
cur = database.cursor
cur.execute('select * from sge_job where state like \'r\'')
result = cur.fetchall()
database.close()
ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
header = ui.tableWidget.horizontalHeader()
for i in range(9):
    header.setSectionResizeMode(i, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
for row_number, row_data in enumerate(result):
    ui.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
    button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(ui.tableWidget)
    button.setText("Clear")
    ui.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row_number, 6, button)
    button.clicked.connect(printrow)
    for colum_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
        ui.tableWidget.setItem(row_number, colum_number,  QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
        print(row_number, colum_number)

def printrow():
print(ui.tableWidget.currentRow())
```

Comment: Clicking the button inside the cell doesn't necessarily select the cell because the focus events from the click are accepted by the button leaving the table unaware that anything has changed. What you could do is override the focusInEvent or the click event of the button and emit a signal to the table to update it's current selection to the cell whose button was clicked.

Comment: @DiegoSantoDomingo expanding what alexpdev said, clicking on a cell widget that accepts focus and/or accepts mouse events will clear the focus from the table (if it had it), but, most importantly, will *never* update the current index. Depending on the needs, there are various solutions, if you clarify why you specifically need the current row when the button is clicked, we might be able to provide a more appropriate answer.

Comment: When i cliked the button i need to pass the current row first colum value to a system command and perfom an update. Im doing this in C++ whith this command:

Comment: QPushButton *pb = qobject_cast<QPushButton *>(QObject::sender());

      int row = pb->objectName().toInt();

Comment: Thanks for your help @musicamante, i have solved this setting the focus to the tablewidget item after pressing the button, and then pasing first colum (table.item(row,0)).text() to the external command.

Comment: @DiegoSantoDomingo I wouldn't rely on that: what if you remove a row? Then the rows used as object names would be just wrong.